# How to disable the use of ReSharper templates in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: resharper

How to disable the use of ReSharper templates in Visual Studio 2019?

**Now.**
Visual Studio 2019 uses ReSharper snippets.

**Expectation.**
Visual Studio 2019 uses its own snippets.

**Pic-1**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper automatically imports C# templates from Visual Studio. You can go to "ReSharper | Tools | Templates Explorer" and uncheck the templates that you do not want to use.

Alternatively, you can entirely turn off ReSharper completion and use Visual Studio's IntelliSense. You also have an option to use VS action "Edit | IntelliSense | Insert snippet" to manually insert a VS snippet.